# .htaccess - Allow directory listing and only certain extension of files to be accessed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to white-list some files on my server, but not disable directory listing.
When I add them to `FilesMatch` it disables directory listing.

My current code:

```
allow from all
Options +Indexes

<FilesMatch ".(dem|dem.bz2)$">
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".(?<!dem|dem.bz2)$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**want to allow only dem and dem.bz2 files to be accessed, anything else should be denied. currently my .htaccess works, but directory listing is disabled**

Filename: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/test/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements what you want to allow and what you want to block?

Comment: want to allow only dem and dem.bz2 files to be accessed, anything else should be denied. currently my .htaccess works, but directory listing is disabled

Comment: Please give samples of filenames that should be allowed?

Comment: any file that end with .dem or dem.bz2 **EXTENSION**. For example: test.dem, dummy.dem.bz2 should be allowed. deny access to any other file that extension doesn't end up with dem or dem2.bz

Comment: Can you not spam unrelated tags like why `bash` or `shell`?

Comment: This question is not about programming. It is about configuring a server software. Voted a close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via a simple `mod_rewrite` rule like this:

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!index\.|.+\.dem(?:\.bz2)?$). - [F,NC]
```

Comment: but directory listing is still disabled

Comment: unfortunately directory listing is still disabled. I added my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf config in description, maybe I need to change something there

Comment: try my updated answer again